# Prevent :hover styles affecting :after content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Due to being unable to edit the markup, I need to make dividers between list items using purely CSS and so am using the following:

```
li:after { 
  content: '|';
}
```

This is fine, works well and [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) isn't an issue. However, when I add a `:hover` effect to each list item, it also changes the styling of the `:after` content. You can see what I mean on the demo below.

Is there a way to get around this?

[Simple version here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bRy6/)

Comment: There is no point of using :after for just a simple '|'. There are other ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest, instead of using `:after` and `content`, use `border-right`. The same kind of output is given by:

```css
li {border-right: 1px solid #999; line-height: 1;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/2bRy6/3/

Comment: +1 @Praveen But it is also creating hover effect on the border.

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of something as simple as this, seems obvious now, thanks!

Comment: @Vivek We can set the border properties dude. It is possible. What is missing in mine?

Comment: Its alright. I thought that the OP doesn't want a hover effect on the border. :)

Comment: @Vivek THAT was the real issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the hover-effect to the link inside the list-item. So instead of using `li:hover` you would use `li:hover a` as a selector.